# Laravel relationship is slow

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I try to run this code

```
Item::with('product_save')->whereHas('product_save', function($q){ 
    $q->where('user_id', 4);
});
```

with

```
paginate(20);
```

Item Model :

```
    class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function product_save()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product_save','product_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

but is so slow my database has more than 1M records.

paroduct_saves table :
[image]

thanks

Comment: try to fetch data using pagination

Comment: You probably haven't set up your indexes properly. Show us the your SQL query and again after using `EXPLAIN` before it.

Comment: I do this with paginate(20); but is so slow.

Comment: select only important fields will sure reduce execution time

Comment: @Marwelln how i can show you the SQL? i don't set any index in database just primary key

Comment: @cha7ta , please show your `product_saves` table fields

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Okey
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OjGA.png

Comment: @cha7ta , can you please add your Item Model

Comment: @SaurabhMistry this my model my Item model:


class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function product_save()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product_save','product_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }
}

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I add same condition in item so for that i need to user her model

Comment: Somehow no any answer that could make eloquent faster than raw query or use query builder, with its relationship when it builds queries to run, it use single query in each row it face that is too long to response. It uses waterfall way to build query... I seek the same answer to prevent rewrite them into query builder but seem nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create index on your tablke like this:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

Comment: for primary key?

Comment: If you select where `user_id` add for `user_id` ex: `CREATE INDEX index_user on table_name (user_id)`

Comment: thanks i doed but is still slow. The query take 2 seconds : select * from `products` where exists (select * from `product_saves` where `products`.`id` = `product_saves`.`product_id` and `user_id` = 2) I have more than 60k records

Answer (score 0):

add below relationship in your ProductSave Model :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class ProductSave extends Model
{
    protected $table='product_saves';
    public $primaryKey='id';


         public function product(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id')->where('active',1);
    }

}
```

now in your controller try this :

```
$products=ProductSave::where('user_id',4)->with('product')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I add same condition in item
 $products = $products->where('active', 1);

how i can add it?

Comment: The query take 2 seconds : select * from `products` where exists (select * from `product_saves` where `products`.`id` = `product_saves`.`product_id` and `user_id` = 2). because i have more than 60K records

Comment: I need to add lot of condition so for that I need to use like Product::has('product_save'). to add condition easy ::where()

Comment: @cha7ta , what do you want ? please describe in detail

Comment: I want to select items in product_saves with multiple option price created_at updated_at seller name... all this conditions in items where user_id in product_saves =2 or 3 ..

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to reduce the number of queries.

This will probably work best for you

```
Item->whereIn('product_id', function ($query) use($request) {
     $query->select('product_id')->from('product_saves')
      ->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
     });
})
```

I have this set up as if your user_id were coming in a Request, maybe it is not.

Bottom line, so long as you have a foreign key in the related table, you can make one query and compare the results using 'WhereIn'

I hope this speeds things up for you.